# PHP - Relative URL to Absolute URL

Tags: php, parsing, url, global, local

I'm parsing HTML files and parsing out the links. Sometimes it comes accross
something like:

```
./dir/dir/lol.html
```

My question is how do I turn this into an absolute url, the parser knows the URL that if found the link on.

For example:

```
parses: http://www.website.com/lol/index.html
find: ./dir/dir/haha.html
```

Then how can I combine this into:

```
http://www.website.com/lol/dir/dir/haha.html
```

Comment: you want define a global variable? you can use define function

Comment: why cant you do a str_replace('href="/','href="http : //www.website.com/',$completePage); on completePage, ignore the spaces in http : //, i kept them intentionally to prevent auto hyperlinking by SO

Comment: I don't want to define a global variable..

Comment: @SwenKooij: It's called relative vs absolute path/url

Comment: Also it always needs to work.. no exceptions.. there must be a function for this.. well at least in C# there is

Comment: @Truth, I regret I didn't use the correct words, maybe you know a solution?

Comment: The function your are looking for is str_replace() :http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Never mind, found it: url_to_absolute( $baseUrl, $relativeUrl);

Comment: This may be what you're looking for? http://www.web-max.ca/PHP/misc_24.php

Comment: @Truth, thanks for pointing out the correct words. One search on google helped me finding the answer.

Comment: @SwenKooij: If you have found the answer yourself, you're welcome to post an answer to your own question, and accept it when you can.

Comment: Are you using the Simple HTML DOM Parser library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to break URLs into their components most importantly `PHP_URL_PATH` to find out the path part of the URL.